# using tabs with a webview

Tags: android, tabs, webview

I am trying to use tabs with a webview but I cant seem to get it to work together, i can only get one or the other to display depending on where i put the webview but not both at the same time.

here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
             <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />    
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView1" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"></WebView>    
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

that way only displays the tabs, if i move the webview above the tabwidget then only the webview displays. how do i get them both to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hat Problems with the TabView too, solved it by using a Tabactivity instead of TabWidget:

```
public class main extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    tabHost = getTabHost();
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences))
            .setContent(new Intent(this,tab1.class)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
            .setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_agenda))
            .setContent(new Intent(this,tab2.class)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3")
            .setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_edit))
            .setContent(new Intent(this,tab3.class)));

    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            if(tabId.equals("tab1")){

            }else if(tabId.equals("tab2")){

            }else if(tabId.equals("tab3")){

            }
        }   
    });
}}
```

Comment: that kind of worked, used your code with a variation of mine but thanks